Is the bundle of the Aharonov-Bohm effect like the tangent bundle of a cylinder or like the tangent bundle of a truncated cone?
Both are trivial bundles, and the natural (metric) connection is flat (curvature-free) for both. The difference between them is that the holonomy of the tangent bundle of the cylinder is trivial while the holonomy of the tangent bundle of the truncated cone isn't. This means that in the case of the cylinder, the horizontal lift of any closed curve to any point of the bundle is closed, while in the case of the truncated cone, the horizontal lifts of nonshrinkable closed curves are not closed. To put it plainly, the parallel transport of any tangent vector around a closed curve in the case of the cylinder returns always to its starting point, while in the case of the truncated cone, this is true only for those curves that don't go around the hole.
One proposed solution to the issue of the non-existing global wave function in the Aharonov-Bohm experiment is the replacement of the wave function with a global horizontal section of an $U(1)$ bundle and getting different local wave functions for different patches in a local trivialization. But this presupposes the existence of global horizontal non-shrinkable sections of the bundle, like in the case of the cylinder. However, the Aharonov-Bohm effect is explained sometimes as a nontrivial holonomy of the (flat) connection due to the magnetic field inside the solenoid. This would be like the truncated cone. But in this case, there is no global horizontal section of the bundle, and we can't repair this with any gauge (trivialization).
So, which is the correct picture? In the first case, there is no problem, but there isn't any holonomy. In the second case, there is the much-talked-about holonomy, but in this case, the trivialization (gauge) doesn't solve anything.

In this post we discuss a very nice pedagogical article by Bernstein & Phillips. In short: the solenoid in the AB-experiment is a cylinder. The fiber bundle geometry of that is analogous to (not is)  the Riemannian geometry (vector bundle) of a truncated cone.

@KurtG. This is very nice but doesn't tell what the state is in this case. It can't be a continuous function and also can't be a global horizontal section since such doesn't exist, so what is it?

Now I remember the long discussion in the post you linked but I have not followed all the details and have not a huge desire to do so. Maybe I am oversimplifying that wave function question but imho AB-experiment is quite similar to the double-slit. In the latter we don't say that there can't be a continuous wave function because it has a different phase depending on whether it goes through one slit or the other. The resolution is that $\psi$ goes through both slits, then interferes on the screen and is perfectly continuous.

In the double slit, the wavefunction is the sum of two other functions and the phases of these two functions are different. Each function is single-valued and continuous and so is their sum. See here (eq. 4)

Requiring (the derivative of) the  wavefunction to be horizontal w.r.t. the $U(1)$-connection is absurd. If you just consider a free particle in space moving in the absence of any field at all (so space is $M=\mathbb{R}^3,$ the principal bundle is the trivial one $P=U(1)\times M,$ and the wavefunction is a section of the associated and also trivial vector bundle $B=M\times\mathbb{C}$ and therefore an ordinary function $\psi:M\to\mathbb{C}$), requiring the wavefunction to be "horizontal" means requiring it to be constant. After all, the connection tells you how to take the derivative of the wavefunction, so "horizontal" means $\frac{d\psi}{dx}=0.$ That's not a reasonable condition!
The only time I could see a (globally) horizontal wavefunction being appropriate for describing the Aharanov-Bohm effect is in the following situation: one particle is confined to a finite ring around a cylindrical solenoid. The flux in the solenoid is a multiple of the flux quantum $h/q$ (perhaps the flux is zero). Then the ground state of the particle is a horizontal section of the appropriate associated bundle. If the flux is not set to a multiple of the flux quantum, then a globally horizontal wavefunction is indeed impossible. This isn't a problem: the ground state is just not horizontal anymore. In particular, the single-valuedness of the wavefunction is not a priori related to the connection and is never in question. (What might happen is someone chooses coordinate charts to make components of the connection vanish. Then the wavefunction will have "multiple" values at the chart overlaps. But the wavefunction is still single-valued! You are just describing its single value at each point in multiple coordinate systems.)
That out of the way, I don't know where the bundles presented in the question come from. I will just describe the bundles and connection in the Aharanov-Bohm effect from first principles. Both bundles involved in the classic Aharanov-Bohm configuration (i.e. a particle moving around an infinite cylindrical solenoid) are trivial. Let $M=\mathbb{R}^3\mathbin\backslash\text{cylinder}$ be the space around the solenoid. The relevant (and only, I believe) principal $U(1)$-bundle on $M$ is the trivial one: $P=U(1)\times M.$
The space of wavefunctions is constructed by first replacing the $U(1)$ fibers of $P$ with $\mathbb{C}$ fibers through the associated bundle construction. This doesn't require the connection, and you get another boring trivial bundle, (isomorphically) $B=M\times\mathbb{C}.$ The wavefunction will be a section $\psi\in\Gamma(B)$ (or, rather, an $L^2$ class of sections of $B$). There is no obstruction to a global section here. In fact, as the bundle is trivial, the wavefunction is an ordinary global function $\psi:M\to\mathbb C,$ like in free space.
The vector potential is interpreted as a principal $U(1)$-connection on $P,$ i.e. a $\mathfrak{u}(1)$-valued $U(1)$-equivariant generator-preserving  1-form on $P.$ As $P$ is a trivial bundle, such an object does always exist. At zero field strength, we have the Maurer-Cartan connection on $P$ (which arises essentially by differentiating the action of $U(1)$ on $P$): $\omega_{MC}=d\phi,$ where $\phi$ is the angular coordinate around $U(1).$ If you restrict attention to a ring around the solenoid instead of the full space $M,$ $P$ restricts to a torus, and the "horizontal" subspaces (of $TP$) picked out by $\omega_{MC}$ are just toroidal circles (i.e. lines of "latitude"). When the solenoid is powered, the connection is instead $\omega=\omega_{MC}+A,$ where the vector potential $A$ is interpreted as a $\mathfrak{u}(1)$-valued 1-form on $M$ (not $P$, and with no further restrictions!). Specifically, letting $\theta$ be the azimuthal coordinate on $M,$ we can take $A=\frac{R^2B}{2}\,d\theta,$ where $\pi R^2B$ is the magnetic flux through the solenoid. The horizontal spaces picked out by $\omega$ on each torus are now "tilted".
Note there is no need for the "integral curves" of $\omega$ (i.e. the spiral paths in $P$ traced out by parallel transporting points on $P$ around circles in $M$) to close. What's important is there exist global choices of "horizontal", both twisted and untwisted, not globally horizontal sections. In particular, the connection imposes no restrictions on $\psi$ nor vice versa. The transport of a point of the wavefunction around the solenoid is allowed to cause a nontrivial phase shift, and will do so if the flux $\pi R^2B$ is not a multiple of the flux quantum $h/q.$

What does "the phase of a moving particle picks up a relative phase change matching the parallel transport" mean? We are talking about a wave function at a given time instance, aren't we? Aharonov and Bohm showed that this function isn't single-valued, since taking a curve $\gamma$ connecting points $a$ and $b$, $$\Delta\psi(b)=\Delta\psi(a)e^{i\frac{q}{\hbar c}\int_\gamma A}$$. where $\Delta\psi=\psi/\psi_0$ where $\psi_0$ is the wafefunction for $B=0$.

Of course, you are right that both bundles are trivial (I've already fixed my silly error in my post), and it's also true that not the wave function must be horizontal, but $\Delta\psi$. But this is also a function, so if it is multiple-valued then so is $\psi$.

@mma No, the wavefunction is not multiple-valued. That wouldn't make sense. If you read A-B's paper, they take pains to assure you the wavefunction is single-valued. That $\int_\gamma A$ is path dependent means only that the "easy" way of solving the Schrodinger equation (start with a solution $\psi_0$ at $A=0,$ then multiply by a position-dependent phase factor) doesn't work (in your notation, $\Delta\psi\neq\psi/\psi_0$). You have to do it by considering the path each "part" of the wavefunction takes. The solution is single-valued.

@mma My note at the end is about time evolution. I'm saying you should start with a wavepacket that, over time, splits and recombines. You'd show that the phase difference between the two pieces as they recombine is the same phase difference as you'd predict by parallel transporting a point on the bundle $B$ (lying over the initial position of the particle in $M$) around to a point on the other side of the solenoid along the two different paths. On second thought, something so involved is probably unnecessary. It is traditional to treat scattering problems with extended incoming waves.

As far as I see, the A-B paper solves the problem of multiple-valuedness  only in a special case when the wave function is $0$ on the line $\theta = \pi$. Of course, where $\psi=0$ and $\psi_0\neq 0$,  $\psi\neq e^{iS}\psi_0$. But if $\psi$ doesn't vanish anywhere then this trick doesn't work.

@mma I quote, "The exact solution, which is needed on this line [$\theta=\pi$], would show that the second term will combine with the first to make a single-valued wave function, despite the non-single-valued character of the two parts, in the neighborhood of $\theta=\pi.$ We shall see this in more detail presently for the special case $\alpha=n+\frac12$" (page 490 of my link, first complete paragraph). They do only present in full the case where $\psi$ vanishes on $\theta=\pi.$ But if you trust their words, there is a single-valued wavefunction even when $\psi$ doesn't vanish on $\theta=\pi.$

@mma And if you don't want to take A-B's word for it, consider the following picture. Consider that, at some point, the wavefunction of an incoming electron is supported entirely/mostly on side of the solenoid. There is no reason to believe (the bulk of) the wavefunction is multiple valued yet. As time passes, the wave passes by the solenoid (which itself is shielded from being hit). How (and why) would the wavefunction develop multiple values? All that happens is that the top part of the wave picks up a phase, the bottom part picks up a different one, and then they interfere.

"There is no reason to believe (the bulk of) the wavefunction is multiple valued yet." - except if I know that $$\Delta\psi(b)=\Delta\psi(a)e^{i\frac{q}{\hbar c}\int_\gamma A}$$ at any time instance between any points $a$ and $b$, specifically also when $b=a$.

@mma I just looked at the paper again, and A-B actually do give outright an exact solution to the Schrodinger equation (their eq. 1) for arbitrary values of the enclosed flux (right above their eq. 5). The only simplifying assumption for this solution is that the radius of the solenoid goes to zero. The solution is $\psi(r,\theta)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^{|m+\alpha|}J_{|m+\alpha|}(r)e^{im\theta}$ (with $\alpha$ a constant proportional to the flux). It is surely not a very pleasant expression, but an infinite sum and some Bessel functions do not threaten the single-valuedness of $\psi.$

But contradicts to $\Delta\psi(b)=\Delta\psi(a)e^{i\frac{q}{\hbar c}\int_\gamma A}$.

@mma The definition of $\Delta\psi$ assumes $\psi/\psi_0$ exists. That is, the definition assumes that the wavefunction when $A$ is present is just the solution with $A=0$ times some spatially varying phase. The point of the A-B effect is this isn't true. There's no reason for $\Delta\psi$ to exist (and it doesn't exist for A-B's solution, since $\psi_0$ is zero in places where $\psi$ isn't) or to mean anything physically. $\Delta\psi,$ when it exists, is the "trick" (to easily solve Schrodinger's equation). If it doesn't exist, oh well. You can still solve Schrodinger's equation.

Where $\psi_0 = 0$, there is a dark fringe in the case of zero magnetic flux. Since in the Aharonov-Bohm experiment fringes are shifted, in these points, generally $\psi\neq 0$. This means that indeed, $\psi=e^{iS}\psi_0$ cannot be true everywhere. Interesting.
